# How do I create a directory and parent directories in one Perl command?

Tags: perl, filesystems, directory, mkdir

In Perl, how can I create a subdirectory and, at the same time, create parent directories if they do not exist?  Like UNIX's mkdir -p command?

Comment: Added this question so I'll be able to find it again easily in the future, instead of looking it up every time.  I always look for this in POSIX.pm, for some reason.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
make_path("path/to/sub/directory");
```

The deprecated mkpath and preferred make_path stemmed from a discussion in Perl 5 Porters thread that's archived [here](http://www.xray.mpe.mpg.de/mailing-lists/perl5-porters/2008-05/msg00209.html).

In a nutshell, Perl 5.10 testing turned up awkwardness in the argument parsing of the makepath() interface.  So it was replaced with a simpler version that took a hash as the final argument to set options for the function.

Comment: @skiphoppy: This still isn't "like UNIX's mkdir -p command" as stated in the question.  mkdir's man page shows <code>       -p, --parents
              no error if existing, make parent directories as needed </code>  But make_path will return false if the directory exists.  (ie, make_path "/tmp/foo" or die; #will die if /tmp/foo exists)

Answer (score 3):

Use mkpath from the File::Path module:

```
use File::Path qw(mkpath);
mkpath("path/to/sub/directory");
```

Comment: Researching this just now, I see that mkpath() is deprecated and the official interface is now make_path().  If someone writes up a great explanation as to what that buys us, I'll make that the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Kindly ignore if you are looking for a Perl module with 'mkdir -p' functionality but the following code would work:

```
my $dir = '/root/example/dir';

system ("mkdir -p $dir 2> /dev/null") == 0 
    or die "failed to create $dir. exiting...\n";
```

You can use a module but then you have to install it on each server you are going to port your code on.  I usually prefer to use system function for a work like mkdir because it's a lesser overhead to import and call a module when I need it only once to create a directory.

Comment: That approach makes sense if you want to avoid installing modules.  I usually prefer to demand the installation of modules I need, or I refuse to support the system. :)  I prefer to use modules so I can reap the benefit of the testing and research that went into them, so I can avoid mistakes such as failing to check system calls or losing output of error messages, and because it's less overhead to not have to create a process.

Comment: Doesn't that create a dependency to the operating system?

Answer (score 0):

ref http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html

"The make_path function creates the given directories if they don't exists [sic!] before, much like the Unix command `mkdir -p`"

Answer (score 0):

mkdir() allows you to create directories in your Perl script.

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $directory = "tmp";

unless(mkdir($directory, 0755)) {
        die "Unable to create $directory\n";
```

This program create a directory called "tmp" with permissions set to 0755 (only the owner has the permission to write to the directory; group members and others can only view files and list the directory contents).