# How to create multiple directories from a single full path in Perl?

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I create a directory and parent directories in one Perl command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050365/how-do-i-create-a-directory-and-parent-directories-in-one-perl-command)

Given this scenario:
I got an id like "37093".
I execute some perl code to create a path name from this

```
my $id = "37093";
my $path = join('/', split(//, $id ) );
```

Path is now: "3/7/0/9/3";

Now i want to recursively create all directories that are still not created.

How can this easiliy be done?

Comment: The language is called Perl or perl not PERL.

Comment: @dgw: i used capital letters to underline the programming language used - changed it back to PERL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`File::Path`](http://p3rl.org/File%3a%3aPath) and [`Try::Tiny`](http://p3rl.org/Try%3a%3aTiny):

```
use File::Path qw(make_path);
use Try::Tiny;

try {
    make_path '3/7/0/9/3';
} catch {
    warn "make_path failed: $_\n";
}
```

Comment: this answer would IMHO be more useful without the non-standard exception handling code.

Comment: i get:  "make_path" is not exported by the File::Path module\nCan't continue after...

Comment: @Thariama: you have an old version of `File::Path` (the current version is v2.08). You shoulld upgrade the module, but in this instance you can get away with replacing `make_path` with `mkpath` everywhere.

Comment: @Alnitak: what form of exception handling do you consider *standard*?

Comment: @Borodin: thanks for the info. i am still not that famililiar with perl. Unfortunately i cannot upgrade the module.

Comment: Either use the legacy interface `mkpath`, or better upgrade the module. You should not run outdated software! [`make_path` already appeared 4 years ago in version 2.06_05](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Path/Changes), and [has since been shipped in 39 releases of Perl](http://perlpunks.de/corelist/mversion?module=File%3A%3APath).

Comment: "cannot upgrade" surely is hyperbole. You can install your own copy of the module, [local::lib](http://p3rl.org/local::lib) makes this easy; also see [How can I install a CPAN module into a local directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540640/how-can-i-install-a-cpan-module-into-a-local-directory).

Comment: @daxim: i am not allowed to install it on enterprise servers

Comment: @Borodin `eval` or using the error handling code built into `make_path`

Comment: The usual retort is: You are not allowed to install a newer version of an existing core Perl module, but you are allowed to install code you got from Stack Overflow? Where's the difference? What makes code from here trustworthier?

Comment: @Alnitak: the use of `eval` for trapping and handling exceptions is perhaps classical, but it involves a lot of non-obvious code to use it safely and properly. The `Try::Tiny` module encapsulates all of that arcane code and renders it in an intuitive syntax without enhancing or modifying the functionality of a simple `eval`. Perl has progressed with leaps and bounds since v5.12, and this module represents part of those advances.

Comment: @Borodin sure, 100% with you.  I just think that _in the context of this answer_ it actually reduces the usefulness of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
mkdir -p $the_path
```

may this help.

or write it yourself, but i find this should help and more elegant:
http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Path.html

Comment: how does this have to look like when called from a script?

Comment: you could use call system to accomplish it. see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

Comment: +1 hmm, works, but is it possible without usage of the system command (doesn't look very elegant) ?

Comment: ehh, yes i think you can write a recursive function your self, like this (sorry that i am not a perl coder): (but how to start a new line)..?

Comment: @Marcus if you're not a Perl coder, why are you answering this question?

Comment: @Alnitak, i think language is just something that you use to tell the computer how to do, but not something what you have to follow :)

Comment: @Marcus Well FWIW I think this is an utterly lousy answer.  Using `system` to accomplish a simple recursive `mkdir` that's implemented in a _standard module supplied with Perl_ is a) inefficient and b) a potential security hole.